# Can I bind the data without store in component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

> In react-redux if we have a list of thousands of record, then in this
>   case should I directly pass the data to the component for
>   rendering.Because data is very large and I think if data is more no
>   need to save in store to improve the performance.Am I correct please assist me.

Comment: You can try using react virtual lists or something like https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/

Comment: except for, don't use that particular table which is dead / deprecated and has memory leak issues when you scroll past an ambiguous point (eg 25k rows) - stops rendering.